# How to Eliminate the Brown Box from xcode 4 PageViewController

Tags: xcode, ipad, xcode4.2

I'm very new to Xcode, and have managed to put together a paged-based app using the build in xcode 4.2 template.  I'm having a few issues, but the pressing one right now is the presence of the brown frame around the iPad version of the app.  the iPhone version displays the NSArray of images perfectly fine, but the iPad version insists on a thick brown border that I can't seem to figure out how to eliminate.  I understand it comes from the Root Controller, but have no idea how to manipulate it through the IB interface, or through the coding interface.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `RootViewController.m` file.
In the code, under the viewDidLoad method, change the default `pageViewRect` to `0.0, 0.0.`
i.e.

```
pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 0.0, 0.0);
```